# How to remove .ds patterned string from a string using python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I have this string

```
a="""SELECT
    transform_abc.ds AS "ds",
    SUM(transform_abc.dollars) AS "dollars",
    transform_abc.unit AS "unit"
FROM fct_table_abc transform_abc
WHERE
    (
        transform_abc.is_charged > 0
        OR transform_abc.account_status = 0
    )
    AND transform_abc.ds = '2020-02-20'
GROUP BY
    transform_abc.ds,
    transform_abc.unit"""
```

I need to remove column with ds from this string after SELECT and GROUP BY but not after WHERE.

Output needed:

```
a="""SELECT
    SUM(transform_abc.dollars) AS "dollars",
    transform_abc.unit AS "unit"
FROM fct_table_abc transform_abc
WHERE
    (
        transform_abc.is_charged > 0
        OR transform_abc.account_status = 0
    )
    AND transform_abc.ds = '2020-02-20'
GROUP BY
    transform_abc.unit"""
```

Tranform_abc is just a table name , it can be any table name. So we cant use that in regex. 
Not sure how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

```
import re

a="""SELECT
    transform_abc.ds AS "ds",
    SUM(transform_abc.dollars) AS "dollars",
    transform_abc.unit AS "unit"
FROM fct_table_abc transform_abc
WHERE
    (
        transform_abc.is_charged > 0
        OR transform_abc.account_status = 0
    )
    AND transform_abc.ds = '2020-02-20'
GROUP BY
    transform_abc.ds,
    transform_abc.unit"""

res = re.sub(r'((?:SELECT|GROUP BY)\s+(?:(?!WHERE)[\s\S])*?)\s+[\w.]+\.ds.+', r'\1', a)
print res
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT

    SUM(transform_abc.dollars) AS "dollars",
    transform_abc.unit AS "unit"
FROM fct_table_abc transform_abc
WHERE
    (
        transform_abc.is_charged > 0
        OR transform_abc.account_status = 0
    )
    AND transform_abc.ds = '2020-02-20'
GROUP BY

    transform_abc.unit
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5BlwPl/1)

---

If the SQL is on a single line, use:

```
((?:SELECT|GROUP BY)\s+(?:(?!WHERE)[\s\S])*?)\s*[\w.]+\.ds[^,]*,
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5BlwPl/2)

Comment: It can be formatted or unformatted. For e.g.  SELECT
    transform_abc.ds AS "ds", SUM(transform_abc.dollars) AS "dollars",
    transform_abc.unit AS "unit"
FROM fct_table_abc transform_abc
WHERE
    (
        transform_abc.is_charged > 0
        OR transform_abc.account_status = 0
    )
    AND transform_abc.ds = '2020-02-20'
GROUP BY  transform_abc.ds,ransform_abc.unit

Comment: @analyst: Do you mean on a single line? Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/5BlwPl/2)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the solution.  This may by syntactically incorrect, have not compiled it but should work logically.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

a="""SELECT 
transform_abc.ds AS "ds",
    SUM(transform_abc.dollars) AS "dollars",
    transform_abc.unit AS "unit"
FROM fct_table_abc transform_abc
WHERE
    (
        transform_abc.is_charged > 0
        OR transform_abc.account_status = 0
    )
    AND transform_abc.ds = '2020-02-20'
GROUP BY
    transform_abc.ds,
    transform_abc.unit"""


a = re.sub("SELECT[\s]+([a-zA-Z0-9.])+_([a-zA-Z0-9.])+.ds", "SELECT ", a)

a = re.sub("SELECT[\s]+[a-zA-Z]+[\s]+(\")ds(\",)","SELECT ",a)

a = res.sub("GROUP BY[\s]+([a-zA-Z0-9.])+_([a-zA-Z0-9.])+.ds,","GROUP BY ",a)
```

## a would contain the final expected result

## Thanks KM